# Confusion about the two coordinate systems in the matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm reviewing linear algebra and was reading through [this](https://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2018/10/24/matrices/#:%7E:text=When%20we%20perform%20matrix%20multiplication,are%20the%20components%20of%20x.) text on developing a geometrical intuition on linear algebra concepts (although the text isn't totally necessary because I'll provide an example). When looking at the matrix equation Ax=b, I'm trying to understand geometrically what is going on. Take for instance the matrix equation $$\begin{bmatrix}2 & -1\\-1 & 2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 3\end{bmatrix}$$

I would like to know if my understanding is correct: In the normal cartesian coordinate system the vector $$x = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}$$ looks like your normal vector that is $$1 \cdot e_1 + 2 \cdot e_2 = (1,2)$$But the above matrix A transforms the cartesian coordinate system into a different looking space (is that the right word?), one where the same vector x from above actually looks like the vector b = (0,3)? I've attached a hand-drawing of what I believe this matrix equation represents.

So is it correct to say that this matrix A takes vector x and results with a vector b, but the vector b = (0,3) is in terms of the original normal cartesian coordinate system and not the one defined by matrix A? My confusion lies in the idea that we are using a new coordinate system A to produce a vector in the old coordinate system. I'd like to know if I've misunderstood something or if that reasoning is correct.

[image: Image of linear transformation]

Comment: Not necessarily. The matrix could just represent a linear function that takes $(1,2)^T$ to $(0,3)^T$.

Comment: @JohnDouma can you elaborate? Is it not correct to think of the matrix as a change of coordinate systems? And the resultant vector in the new coordinate system as (0, 3) in the original? And if not, why?

Comment: Matrices represent linear functions. Functions map values in the domain to values in the codomain. It's just like any other function. An invertible matrix can represent a change of basis function but it doesn't have to.

Comment: @JohnDouma I think I understand. But if I were to think of this matrix as a change of basis - is it correct to say that the resultant vector b has its coordinates (0,3) that are still in the original coordinate system (a) as per the picture above? A vector with coordinates (0,3) using the basis vectors in the coordinate system (b) would look different than vector b as it is drawn. That is what I meant originally - are the new vector's components still given relative to coordinate system (a)?